# How to work with libraries that don't support async?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, cx-oracle, aiohttp

I'm moving from flask to aiohttp and I need to execute some queries in Oracle db, which doesn't support async. So I'm wondering how to do that in aiohttp?

How about this?

http://pastebin.com/nbWABbvK

Or there's other (right) way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not everything needs to be asynchronous. You can use the library just as you would without asyncio.

Comment: I must to do that in async way, because my app would be blocked for other clients

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) coroutine does exactly that:

```
result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, sync_fn, *args)
```

Using your example:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

async def hello(request):
    param1, param2 = get_params(request)
    result = await app.loop.run_in_executor(executor, sync_fn, param1, param2)
    return web.Response(text=result)
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but you didn't understand me, I'm using aiohttp, updated example code

Comment: I must use app loop, not create new one?
And I've read source code if I'll pass None as executor it will create threadpoolexecuter for me with 5 workers!

Comment: @Howtochangeusername Absolutely, you can only have one loop running at a time. And yes, the default executor is a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 5 workers.

Comment: but I need to create and pass new executor because I don't want to use resourses of app's executor or None is just fine?

Comment: @Howtochangeusername Using the default executor is perfectly fine.